# Django - annotate latest child's column value to query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I have a Trade, which is the parent of TradeLeg.
I am now querying the trade and I need to annotate the "date" of the latest TradeLeg added to this query.

Here's my models:

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        default='',
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        default='',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )


class TradeLeg(models.Model):
    trade = models.ForeignKey(
        Trade,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        default='',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Here's my erroneous query:

```
trades = Trade.objects.all().annotate(latest_leg_date='tradeleg__date__first')
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30528268

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [**`Max()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#max) function

```
from django.db.models import Max

trades = Trade.objects.all().annotate(latest_leg_date=Max('tradeleg__date'))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the simplest and professional way to get latest trades

```
latestTrades = Trade.objects.filter().order_by('-tradeleg__date')
```

However, if you use  **Max** or **Min** function it will gives the same query.So that it can be cause an error