# Django Queryset Annotate value with latest related object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have three models: Brand, Log and Abstract MWModel.

```
class Log(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=get_modules())
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    method = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=HTTP_METHODS)
    url = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    code = models.IntegerField()
    message = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.created_at.isoformat()


class MWModel(models.Model):
    log = GenericRelation(Log)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Brand(MWModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can get **code** field of last Log record created for each Brand?

I have this

```
Brand.objects.filter(
    merchant=account.merchant,
    identity__app=F('merchant__erp')
).annotate(
    log__last__created_at=Max('log__created_at'),
    log__last__code=Log.objects.filter(
        content_type__model=Brand._meta.model_name,
        object_id=OuterRef('pk')
    ).order_by('-created_at').values('code')[:1]
).values('pk', 'name', 'log__last__created_at', 'log__last__code')
```

And i need something like this

```
Brand.objects.filter(
    merchant=account.merchant,
    identity__app=F('merchant__erp')
).annotate(
    log__last__created_at=Max('log__created_at'),
    log__last__code=F('log__code', filter=Q('log__created_at'=F('log__last__created_at')))
).values('pk', 'name', 'log__last__created_at', 'log__last__code')
```

But I have not found how to code something similar.

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotate with latest related object in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528268/annotate-with-latest-related-object-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via a subquery. You were really close, just missing a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expression.

```
Brand.objects.annotate(
    log__last__code=Subquery(
        Log.objects.filter(
            content_type__model=Brand._meta.model_name,
            object_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-created_at').values('code')[:1]
    )
)
```

Comment: Hello Alexandr, without Subquery the annotate also works for me. I really need is replace Subquery by expressions in annotate **log__last__code**. So I get `log__last__created_at=Max('log__created_at')` and I need something similar to get **log__last__code**

Comment: No way it's working without the Subquery expression...Do you want to `get code field of last Log record created for each Brand?` or do you want to replace Subquery with something else? I was giving a solution for the first question.

Comment: Wait, what? It **is** working without the Subquery, but that's weird. What's the problem, then?

Comment: I think my question is not clear, I need an expression that allows me to get the code of the last Log without using Subquery. Something similar to how I get **log__last__created_at**.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since you cannot `Max` the `code` by `created_at`. So that trick only works when you want Max/Min of the same column. What's your issue with the Subquery, though? Sounds like an X/Y problem to me