# Django ListView - getting the most recent related object and preventing Django from caching the view or database query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a `Campaign` model and a `CampaignStatus` model whose foreign key is the `Campaign` model. When a Campaign is edited or created it will pass through several statuses and will have a `CampaignStatus` object associated with each status change.

Using Django's CBVs, I have a list view that shows a users Campaigns, and I want to pass the most recent status in the context to the template.

Django seems to be caching the status and I don't know how to prevent it. (Possibly relevant: the Django admin campaign view also has the same caching problem - I've defined a method to get the most recent status. The Django admin `CampaignStatus` list view behaves as expected, always showing new statuses as soon as they're created.)

I would like the cache to be 5 seconds, but it appears to be about 3 minutes. How can I change this?

A code snippet from the generic ListView we're using:

```py
@method_decorator(cache_page(5), name="dispatch") # single arg is seconds
class CampaignsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Campaign
    paginate_by = 100

    template_name = "writing/user_campaigns.html"
    context_object_name = "user_campaigns"


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        for i, _ in enumerate(context.get("user_campaigns")):
            campaign = context["user_campaigns"][i]
            campaign_status = CampaignStatus.objects.filter(campaign=campaign).latest("-status")
            context["user_campaigns"][i].status = campaign_status.get_status_display()

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Campaign.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-modified")

    #... some other methods too
```

Comment: Are you calling change_list_view anywhere inside admin.py? If not, it seems unlikely to be an issue with the view. Does it do the same thing in different browsers? What about disabling cache in dev tools in each browser? You could try to use the url cache_page method just to see what happens.

Comment: As a side note you are performing an extra query for every `Campaign` object to get the latest status. You could look into annotating the latest related object with a subquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023303/django-queryset-annotate-value-with-latest-related-object

Answer (score 0):

I think your can find better solution, but u can write post_save signal dropping invalidate cache.
Somthing like that:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
def invalidate_cache_page(
    view: str,
    path_params: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    key_prefix: str = '',
    partial: bool = True
) -> None:
    """
    Invalidate page cache.
    """
    cache_key = generate_cache_key(view, path_params, {}, key_prefix, partial)
    if hasattr(cache, 'keys'):
        keys = cache.keys(cache_key) or []
        cache.delete_many(keys)
    else:
        cache.delete(cache_key)
```

generate_cache_key your own func for generating